# Adding categories to an Atom feed from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rss, atom-feed

I can't seem to get the syntax correct for adding categories to blog posts.

**index.atom.builder**

```
atom_feed language: 'en-US', schema_date: 2013 do |feed|
  feed.title @title
  feed.updated @updated

  @posts.each do |post|
    next if post.updated_at.blank?
    feed.entry post, published: post.published_at do |entry|
      entry.title post.title
      entry.summary post.summary.blank? ? truncate("#{strip_tags(post.content)}", length: 140, separator: ' ') : strip_tags(post.summary)
      entry.content post.content, type: 'html'
      entry.author do |author|
        author.name post.user ? post.user.name : post.author
      end
      post.categories.map {|c| c.name}.each do |t|
        entry.category term: t, label: t, scheme: 'http://mywebsite.com'
      end
    end # end feed.entry
  end # end @posts.each
end
```

Answered all my own questions.  For anyone hitting this, this will give you a validated atom feed!  Passing the `published:` value in the `|entry|` block is only necessary if you don't want to use the default `created_at` and `updated_at` values.  Check your feed at http://validator.w3.org/feed/ to check yours!

Comment: You need to separate out your answer into the answer section and then mark it as accepted by the tick. Otherwise it keeps coming up as unanswered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up using.  This actually gets 2 different models into the feed.

**views/entries/feed.atom.builder**

```
atom_feed language: 'en-US', schema_date: 2013 do |feed|
  feed.title @title
  feed.updated @updated

  @entries.each do |e|
    next if e.updated_at.blank?
    feed.entry e do |entry|
      entry.title e.name
      entry.summary e.summary.blank? ? truncate("#{strip_tags(e.content)}", length: 140, separator: ' ') : strip_tags(e.summary), type: 'html'
      entry.content e.content, type: 'html'
      entry.author do |author|
        author.name e.user.name
      end
      e.categories.map {|c| c.name}.each do |t|
        entry.category term: t, label: t, scheme: root_url
      end
      entry.category term: 'blog', label: 'blog', scheme: root_url
    end # end feed.entry
  end # end @entries.each

  @designs.each do |d|
    next if d.updated_at.blank?
    feed.entry d do |entry|
      entry.title d.name
      entry.summary truncate("#{strip_tags(d.content)}", length: 140, separator: ' '), type: 'html'
      entry.content d.content, type: 'html'
      entry.author do |author|
        author.name User.first.name
      end
      d.categories.map {|c| c.name}.each do |t|
        entry.category term: t, label: t, scheme: root_url
      end
      entry.category term: 'design', label: 'design', scheme: root_url
    end # end feed.entry
  end # end @designs.each
end
```